# CSS3 On Focus Animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, frontend

I am trying to create a one page site and I wish to add CSS3 animation effects. I wish them to load only when the elements are in focus or show up on the screen as in the below examples

http://iplayinsandboxes.com/

http://joy-interactive.com/thats-joy

I know they are transitions. But not really sure how do we load them.

Any advice and readymade toolkits / jQuery will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Maybe this will help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand you - by "focus" you mean what window was scrolled and now some block is visible, like in your example.

If so, i think  [this plugin](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) should help you